# Leveraging browser caching for Wordpress & login issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, caching, optimization, browser-cache

Since I don't really want to use a Wordpress plugin to leverage browser caching, I was refering to the document below to write some code in htaccess file.

[leveraging browser caching guide](http://crunchify.com/how-to-speed-up-wordpress-leveraging-browser-caching-via-htaccess/)

My htaccess came up as below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Now that I have successfully leverage browser caching, I was looking around my Wordpress website to see if it works well. Then I found a problem with login.

I logged into the wordpress, clicked other pages like 'about us' page and it shows I am not logged in.  I clicked the login page to re-login and it suddenly shows I am logged in.  Now I visit other pages like 'home' page and it again shows I am not logged in.

It seems like the caching is preventing me from staying logged in certain pages such as homepage, aboutus, and contactus pages.  When I click dynamic pages such as login, myaccount page, it shows that I am logged in.

I am trying to see where to start to troubleshoot this issue. I use these plugins for my wordpress website; contactform, woocommerce, learndash, etc. 
I am not using any kind of caching plugin such as w3 total cache.

Comment: try removing that htaccess code and check if it resolves the issue?

Comment: This is what I use before I switched to WPRocket, which is freaking amazing. You will not get a better caching plugin. From 3-4 seconds to less than 700 milliseconds with that turned on. The order of your .htaccess probably matters, I don't do much with this since plugins do the trick and I can focus on other stuff. https://gist.github.com/carasmo/9a33f15c968d6b14134b61279f1468fd

Comment: Yasir removing the htacess code resolves the login issue. @Christina Thank you so much for the github link. I tried the code in that link and still doing the same thing. I am not sure why this is happening. I might consider using WPRocket if I can't figure out this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found why this is happening:

```
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
```

=> setting up expire header for html contents obviously cached my html page and it was messing up with the login function. I removed this.

```
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
```

=> I also removed this so my html doesn't get cached by default 1 month.

Problems were solved when I removed those two lines above.

Comment: I have the same problem with you. I tried to use other methods such as disabling caching when user was logged-in and adding no cache on the meta headers but all of those are not working and this is only way that solve my problem by removing `ExpiresByType text/html` & `ExpiresDefault` in Leverage Browser Caching. Thank you @ChrisP777